# Is tor browser and anon surf both the same?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, deanonymization, torproject.org

I am very new to using proxy chains, and since I was worried about messing up while setting up a proper proxy chain I have been using tor browser. Is using tor browser same as using proxy chain using tor's nodes in the relay? or are they different. And which one is more safer more a naive user.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. Tor doesn't just send your data from node to node, it is also encrypted 3 times. Each time your data goes from node to node, one level of encryption is removed until you get to the website that you are using.

What ProxyChains does is that it sends your connection through multiple SOCKS/HTTP(S) proxy servers but without the added protection of encryption with Tor.

Furthermore, Tor Browser makes you look like all other Tor Browser users. I use this illustration: imagine being in a room of people who look alike and have the exact same clothes of the same color. This is what using the Tor Browser does for you. You are one of many and it would be very difficult to pick you out. You do not get this protection from other technologies.

Comment: I have one question which might sound completely dumb. Are three nodes enough to ensure complete of anonymity

Comment: From the Tor FAQ:

We don't want to encourage people to use paths longer than [3] as it increases load on the network without (as far as we can tell) providing any more security. Also, using paths longer than 3 could harm anonymity, first because it makesdenial of security attacks easier, and second because it could act as an identifier if only a small number of users have the same path length as you.

https://support.torproject.org/misc/misc-11/